# The genus of the following algebraic curve(tetragonal curve)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

$$\mathcal F(\lambda, y) =    {y}^{4}- \left( 2 {\lambda}^{8}+{\lambda}^{4}+2 \right) {y}^{3}+ \left( 2 {\lambda}^{16}+4 {\lambda}^{14}+3 {\lambda}^{12}  +4 {\lambda}^{2}+2 \right) {y}^{2} \\-4 {\lambda}^{2}\left(  {\lambda}^{20}+ {\lambda}^{16}+4 \right) y+{\lambda}^{4}(4 {\lambda}^{24}-3 {\lambda}^{20}+4 )=0$$
I am trying to construct the Riemann theta function solution of a soliton equation. The curve comes from the characteristic polynomial of the Lax pair of the soliton equation.

Noting that the curve is singular at the origin, I want to know if it is possible to make the curve a compact Riemann surface. If so, what is its genus, the local coordinates at the origin?

Comment: The **magma** code
  
**A<x,y> := AffineSpace(Rationals(),2);
P := y^4 - (2*x^8+x^4+2)*y^3 + (2*x^16+4*x^14+3*x^12+4*x^2+2)*y^2 - 4*x^2*(x^20+x^16+4)*y + x^4*(4*x^24-3*x^20+4);
C := Curve(A,P);
Genus(C);**

returns **41**.

Comment: The curve can be closed up in $\mathbb P^2$ and made into a compact Riemann surface by resolving the singularities (on affine part, and at the infinity, which is typically singular). To calculate the genus of the smooth model, one way is to calculate the Milnor numbers at these singular points.

Comment: [Crosspost from MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4053225/the-genus-of-the-following-algebraic-curvetetragonal-curve).

Comment: Maple confirms that the genus is 41, and the projective closure has two singularities, one at $(0,0,1)$ and another at $(0,1,0)$ in homogeneous coordinates $(\lambda,y,z)$.